# excel concatenate with "²" or squared symbol

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2019

I would like to use a concatenate formula in Excel that also includes the superscript number 2 (squared symbol), but this does not work with the following input. The formula is roughly like this:

`=CONCATENATE("13";"²")`

i want to get an output like this:

`13²`

I tried using superscript functions on the font
but it didn't work when the text is inside the concatenation.

I have to use concatenate because I want to automate.

Is it possible to do with Excel 2019 there? or is it possible but would require VBA?

Comment: It is possible using `VBA`.

Comment: I used `CONCAT()` and `CONCATENATE()` no problem. Your example also works for me (with English delimiter). I have Excel 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try
=CONCATENATE("13";CHAR(178))

Comment: This is an **extremely** limited solution. How do you handle the powers that contain characters other than 1, 2 or 3? This needs to be modified to accept (account for) the Unicode notation, say, of the 4th power: "U+2074".

Comment: Fyi Posted a solution extending your answer by comprising all superscript digits @DomingosJunqueira

Answer (score 1):

**Using superscript digits via udf**

Superscript digits ranging from 0 to 9 have code values in different unicode sections. Thus using the following *user defined function* *(udf)* allows you to get **each** *digit* from **0** to **9** as superscript character without the need to detect & memorize each code value again and again.

*The hexadecimal and decimal codes are commented in the function below*:

```
Function sup(ByVal digit As Long)
Dim n As Long
Select Case digit
    Case 0: n = &H2070         ' dec 8304
    Case 1: n = &HB9           ' dec 185
    Case 2: n = &HB2           ' dec 178
    Case 3: n = &HB3           ' dec 179
    Case Else                  ' <super> 4 .. 9
        n = &H2074 + digit - 4 ' dec 8308 .. 8313
End Select
sup = ChrW(n)
End Function
```

**Some examples** (~~> output `x³`)

```
    ="x" & sup(3) 
    =CONCAT("x",sup(3))
    =CONCAT("x",sup(Sheet1!A2))   ' assuming a digit value of 3 in Sheet1!A2
```

[image: udf example]
or within VBA assignments like e.g.

```
Sub ExampleCall()
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To 9
    Sheet1.Range("A2").Offset(i).Value = "x" & sup(i)
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you do it as given below.

=13&char(178)

and 179 for cube.

[subscript use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlIH1.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I also found a way to make this work without using concatenate, it just requires making a table to map to superscript numbers.

Step 1: Characters Table

Somewhere else, build a simple table with a map from "Digit" numbers to "Superscript" numbers.
In the first column, "Digit", just type something like:

-9

-8

-7

-6

-5

-4

-3

-2

-1

0

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

In the second column, "Superscript", go to Excel Ribbon Insert > Symbol. In the tab "Symbol", change the comboboxes "Font" to "(normal text)" and "Subset" to "Superscripts and Subscripts".  Insert now each character in its corresponding cell be sure to use "Superscript Minus" for negative numbers. Superscripts 1, 2 and 3 are located in the subset "Latin-1 Supplement".

-9 ⁻⁹
-8 ⁻⁸
-7 ⁻⁷
-6 ⁻⁶
-5 ⁻⁵
-4 ⁻⁴
-3 ⁻³
-2 ⁻²
-1 ⁻¹
0 ⁰
1 ¹
2 ²
3 ³
4 ⁴
5 ⁵
6 ⁶
7 ⁷
8 ⁸
9 ⁹

And so on. Please notice that these are not "formatted" numbers, but special symbols with no numeric value.

Step 2: Vlook Function

Put the digit you want displayed normally in a column, set up like it is in 'A1' below, i.e.:

Cell A1: 13

Then, put the number you want to be displayed in superscript format, i.e.:

Cell B1: 3

Then, use this function to create the final output.

Cell C1: =A1&VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$20,2,FALSE)